# Why does this JSONP call fail?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

Link with working example as to the issue I am having:
http://jsfiddle.net/dSJCq/3/

```
function populateJobsList (jobLocation) {
    if (jobLocation == ""){
        jobLocation = 'Spain';
    }

    var provinceArray = jobLocation.split(',');
    console.log(provinceArray , jobLocation);
    var province = provinceArray[0];
    var url_jobs = "http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=5656845852938153&v=2&format=json&callback=?&q=&l=Madrid&sort=relevance&radius=25&st=jobsite&jt=fulltime&start=0&limit=4&fromage=10&filter=1&latlong=1&co=es";

    $.getJSON(url_jobs, getJSONData);
}


function getJSONData(data) {
        console.log(data)
        $.each(data.results, function(i,item){
            i++;

        $("#titleJob"+i).html(item.jobtitle.substr(0,43));

        if (item.city){
            $("#locationJob"+i).html(item.city);
        }
        else {
            $("#locationJob"+i).html('N/A');
        }

        $("#companyJob"+i).html(item.company.substr(0,43));
    });
}
```

I don't seem to understand why this JSON call fails when i'm trying to retrieve the information from Indeed. In my development environment when i run this exact same code from http://localhost:8080/ the code runs fine and is able to get the results JSON from Indeed. However when I run the code from another server, such as my production server (or JS fiddle) i get an error stack on the $.getJSON call. This error can be viewed in the console on the JS fiddle when you click the test button.

The call is using JSONP, which my understanding of is that it should allow a different access origin, due to the nature of the call. I also know that Indeed supports JSONP, because when you visit this link directly it returns a JSON object with a callback function:

http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=5656845852938153&v=2&format=json&callback=jQuery1710167889759875834_1331926740707&q=&l=Madrid&sort=relevance&radius=25&st=jobsite&jt=fulltime&start=0&limit=4&fromage=10&fil

I'm totally stumped here as to why this code works on one environment but not another?

Comment: The jsFiddle works for me - no error in the console, and the data shows up correctly, running Chrome. What error are you seeing?

Comment: fiddle works for me too.

Comment: http://postimage.org/image/faxg5kv0b/full/

Comment: Are the divs populating with content for everyone?

Comment: Found the issue, Developer version of Chrome >.<

Comment: i just try in google  chrome update '17.0.963.79 m'  that is work